# C# How to print/show the ''difference'' between all numbers in an Array and the average

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and trying to learn the concept of arrays. In my program, I want to show the difference between all the numbers in the array and the average. I only managed to print 1 element(number) in the array with the difference.

If you try to run my program it is divided into 3 parts. the last part is where I am stuck. it only prints the last(19th) element/difference of the array instead of all the Elements.

Any tips are welcome :)
(FYI, I did not yet learn the concept of methods/functions.)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Elements = new int[20]; // this creates/declares an integer array with 20 Elements

            double avg = 0, sum = 0, diff = 0; // declare average variable


            for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Length; i++) // this is a loop to show the random numbers of elements
            {
                int Element = i; // declare the Element variable

                Random rn = new Random();
                int numbers = rn.Next(0, 200); // creates a number between 0 and 200

                Console.WriteLine("Element {0} is {1}", Element, numbers); // print values

                sum += numbers; // calculate the sum of numbers
                avg = sum / Elements.Length; // calculate average of the sum

                if (avg > numbers) // calculate diffrence
                {
                    diff = avg - numbers;
                }
                else
                {
                    diff = numbers - avg;
                }

                if (Element == 19)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", avg);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                    for (int z = 0; z < Elements.Length; z++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Diffrence between Element {0} and average is: {1}", Element, Math.Abs(diff));
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "the difference between all numbers"? What would be the difference of `{ 1, 2, 3 }`? Is it the difference between the lowest and highest number? Or betwen the first and the last one? Or ...?

Comment: Try changing `if (Element == 19)` to `if (x == 19)` or, even better to `if (x == Elements.Length - 1)`. Currently you are only printing, if `Elements.Length` returns `19` (because of your `if (Element == 19)` check).

Comment: @HimBromBeere The difference between each number in the array and the *mean*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I made sure the number was added to the array.
2. The creation of the Random instance should be outside the array otherwise the generated numbers won't be random.
3. Adjusted the last loop.

   ```
        int[] Elements = new int[20]; // this creates/declares an integer array with 20 Elements

        double avg = 0, sum = 0, diff = 0; // declare average variable

        Random rn = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Length; i++) // this is a loop to show the random numbers of elements
        {
            int Element = i; // declare the Element variable

            int numbers = rn.Next(0, 200); // creates a number between 0 and 200

            Console.WriteLine("Element {0} is {1}", Element, numbers); // print values

            Elements[Element] = numbers;

            sum += numbers; // calculate the sum of numbers
            avg = sum / Elements.Length; // calculate average of the sum                            
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("The average is: {0}", avg);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        for (int z = 0; z < Elements.Length; z++)
        {
            diff = Elements[z] - avg;
            Console.WriteLine("Diffrence between Element {0} and average is: {1}", z, Math.Abs(diff));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
   ```

Comment: Thanks, i now understand what i did wrong. bless you and upvote!